# How do can I prevent a tr from expanding beyong a td's border radius?

Tags: css, html-table, border-radius

I'm trying to style a table so that the first and last td in a row have rounded corners, but also so  the tr has a background color that when the tds have a specific class applied to them with a transparent background, it matches other elements on a page. The background color of the tr may change to various colors, but the td transparent color is consistent.

The problem I'm running into seems to be twofold:

1. tr's can't have a border-radius to match the first and last child tds.
2. tr's can't be masked to hide the parts of the tr that expend beyond the tds.

Right now this is what the edges of the table cells look like.

[image: Depiction of the edges of the table cells]

And here is some of the CSS for that (rest is in the jsfiddle linked below).

```css
tbody tr td {
    padding: 0.5em;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}

tbody tr td:not(.colored){
    border-top-color: var(--accent);
    border-bottom-color: var(--accent);
}

tbody tr td:first-child {
    border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    border-left-width: 2px;
    border-left-style: solid;
}

tbody tr td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    border-right-width: 2px;
    border-right-style: solid;
}

tbody tr td:first-child:not(.colored) {
    border-left-color: var(--accent);
}

tbody tr td:last-child:not(.colored) {
    border-right-color: var(--accent);
}
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: This is what I'm trying to achieve]

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VeryColdAir/pex57yru/24/) that shows the problem and the html/css.

If there is not way to prevent the tr from expanding beyond the td, or otherwise apply some kind of border radius to the tr to prevent prevent this, is there another way to solve this?